# Enviar mensaje a través de socket a un cliente especifico con Socket.IO de PHP

Tags: php, socket.io

Necesito enviar un mensaje a un cliente conectado a un servidor de socket pero necesito que solo se envié a una persona, y no una difusión como tal. He leído que con la función `to()` de **socket.IO** se puede pero la he implementado de varias manera y no lo consigo, lo envía a todas.

Este es mi código:

```
$socket->on('new message', function($message) use($socket) {
    $socket->emit("new message", array(
        "username" => $socket->username,
        "action" => "me",
        "message" => [ "from" => $socket->username['WP_USER_DATA']['guid'], "type" => "user", "time" => date('H:i'), "message" =>  $message ]
    ));
    #:: AQUI NECESITO AYUDA
    $socket->broadcast->emit("new message", array(
        "username" => $socket->username,
        "action" => "chat",
        "message" =>  [ "from" => $socket->username['WP_USER_DATA']['guid'], "type" => "", "time" => date('H:i'), "message" =>  $message ]
    ));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

actualmente mi projecto corre con socket.io y php y la forma en la que envio mensajes personales en tiempo real es con el atributo data de html, sesiones de php y un poco de logica.

si estas usando las sessiones de php y socket io es necesario que tambien emitas el **id**  de el usuario que le quieres enviar ese mensaje, para enviarlo y leerlo de la forma que yo lo aria  seria algo como...

la zona en el que el mensaje sera mostrado por ejemplo en un div

```
//usamos la el atributo data de html para cojer el id del usuario

    <div class="recivir" id="recivir" data-message="<?php echo$_GET["id"]?>"></div>
```

luego hacemos una condicion en javascript para agregar el id de el usuario al que deceamos emitir el mensaje ejemplo

```
//emito el mensaje

    socket.emit("new message",{

                 message:message, //emitir mensaje
                 id: id //emitir id del usuario receptor

              });



//recivo el mensaje
    socket.on('new message', function(data){

          var actualuser = $(".recivir").attr(data-message);//el atributo data guardara agregamos el id de el usuario receptor

         //condicion que enviara el mensaje al usuario espesifico

         if(actualuser==data.id){

             actualuser.append(data.message)//aqui jugarias con lo que deceas agregar en el div

         }

               })
```

actualmente encontraras poco material de acuerdo a este tema, lo digo por experiencia propia pero investigue y soluciones mi propio problema.

debes informarte bien como funcionan el atributo data de html, hay muchas formas de hacer lo que nececitas pero esta es la que yo manejo mejor